# context in linux getting SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, scope

I am new to this context stuff of the user defined threads. I wrote a simple program on the contexts... but its giving me segmentation error...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ucontext.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void fun1()
{
cout<<"from 1";
}
void fun2()
{
cout<<"from 2";
}
int main()
{
ucontext_t a,b;
cout<<"y";
getcontext(&b);
b.uc_link=0;
b.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(32767);
b.uc_stack.ss_size=32767;
b.uc_stack.ss_flags=0;
makecontext(&b, fun1, 0);   
getcontext(&a);
a.uc_link=&b;
a.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(32767);
a.uc_stack.ss_flags=0;
makecontext(&a, fun2, 0);
setcontext(&a);
return 0;
}
`
I want to know how to allocate memory using
```

> new
>   rather than **malloc**?? any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten:

```
a.uc_stack.ss_size=32767;
```

Comment: Oops! sorry ... and thanQ.. :) :)

Comment: From man page:  POSIX.1-2008 removes the specifications of makecontext() and swapcontext(), citing portability issues, and recommending that applications  be  rewritten
       to use POSIX threads instead.